# Linear Algebra Problem: Solve for X

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been spending way to much time looking at this. Should probably be easy but I need some help.

$$
\begin{bmatrix}-9 & 4\\ 7 & -9\end{bmatrix}X
+ \begin{bmatrix}7 & 4\\2 & 2\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}-4 & 1\\ -4 & -8\end{bmatrix}X
$$

[Problem Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzEoL.png)

Comment: Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and add at least some minimal context, then find formatting tips at [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and use them. `I've been spending way to much time looking at this` That alone won't solve it. What have you tried, and where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 2):

Rearrange in the form $(A-B)X=C$, then find the inverse if  $A-B $ if this is invertible, or use row reduction.